# JsonResponse в django или динамическое получение данных от сервера

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, ajax, django

Пытаюсь сделать динамическое получение данных от сервера.

views.py

```
def special_data(request):
data = "Privet"
return JsonResponse({'data': data})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('editor/', views.index),
path('json/special_data/', views.special_data)
]
```

editor.html

```
<button onclick="primer()"></button>
```

jQuery/JS

```
function primer() {

$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/editor/json/special_data/', function (data) { //data is the JSON string
    console.log(data);
});

 }
```

И получаю ошибку GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/editor/json/special_data/ 404 (Not Found)
Куда копать, может кто сталкивался?

Comment: У Вас нет пути `/editor/json/special_data/` в `urlpatterns`. Замените в `JavaScript`'е ссылку на `http://127.0.0.1:8000/json/special_data/` и попробуйте снова.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Спасибо вам большое! Можете, пожалуйста, написать это как ответ, чтобы те кто столкнулись с похожей проблемой знали, что делать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас нет пути `/editor/json/special_data/` в `urlpatterns`.

Либо добавьте путь:

***urls.py:***

```py
...
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('/editor/json/special_data/', views.special_data),
]
```

Либо используйте существующий:

***JavaScript:***

```js
function primer() {

  $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/json/special_data/', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```